# USB pen drive asking for drivers?

Tags: usb

I use a PNY 8GB pendrive without any problems at my home pc. But on my office pc its asking for drivers to be installed!! 
Why is that? I thought pendrives were supposed to work out of the box, which it did on my home pc effortlessly. Both are windows XP sp 2 machines
Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, it might be time to apply Service Pack 3...

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem on different machines (asking for inbox drivers). It is likely that the catalog cache somehow became corrupt. Delete the „catroot2” folder in system32 (ONLY THE ONE WITH A „2”!) and restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the first time this usb controller (including nearby usb ports) sees a usb flash drive, it will indeed ask for drivers on Windows XP.

The driver is common, so after that, you won't need any driver for any other flash drive plugged there. But it has to be done once, and since you are at work, I'm guessing you will have to call your sysadmin for him to give administrative rights to this task.

Comment: It's an unusual cases - the Mass Storage Controller driver is usually already in the system, and automatically picks up flash drives.

I suspect he got hit by some malware or something.

Comment: yes its the first time. I have admin rights and I get the windows prompt asking me to point to a location where the drivers are. The thing is I dont know where to point to. When I select 'automatically detect', nothing happens; it just keeps searcing for ever..

Comment: In this case, strange indeed. Because I have seen cases where the driver wouldn't install the first time, due to lack of admin rights, but with admin rights, it should indeed be installed directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the "Mass Storage Controller' drivers. Hunt for it in Google, download it and install.

[download driver here](http://tc.versiontracker.com/product/redir/lid/423892/windowsupdate.microsoft.com)